# sending mail through gmail smtp from .net

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, gmail

I have a few domains set up on the gmail servers through a few different accounts.

I can successfully send mail using the following code from one of the accounts (using the credentials I use to log into the cpanel), but when I try and send mail from one of the user accounts (using that user's credentials), nothing goes out.

Is there a setting I need to set on the gmail side to enable this?

here is the code that works but from only the "parent" account on one of my domains:

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someaddress@somedomain.com", "somepassword");
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("someuser@someotherdomain.com"));
        msg.Subject = "Inquiry from blah blah blah";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = "blah blah blah";
        msg.From = new MailAddress("someaddress@somedomain.com");
        client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to send mail frim gmail servers, you must use gmail credentials not your domain credentials.

for example use someaddress@gmail.com  & your gmail password.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("recipient@yahoo.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("sommeemail@gmail.com", "sender name");
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sommeemail@gmail.com","password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;    
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I am using a hosted domain at Gmail.  Like I said, it works for the "main" email address, just not others.  Surely there's a way to make it work for all.